# TryCatch jump to the catch

Tags: java, try-catch

How can i jump to the catch block in a try catch :

> ```
> try{
>
> if(bla!=)
> throws Exception();
>
> }catch(exception){
> //do
> }
> ```

doesn't work ?

Comment: Define `doesn't work`. Do you have compile time error? Does your code not throw exception? Or maybe exception is handled by different catch block?

Comment: What do you mean by _doesn't work_? You have serious syntax errors in your code snippet.

Comment: Yeah you've got 4 syntax errors that I can see, off the top of my head.

Answer (score 5):

`bla!=`  should be followed by a condition, `throws` should be `throw`, `Exception()` should be `new Exception()`, `exception` should be `Exception e`

```
try {
 if (bla != null) // or anything else
  throw new Exception("Exception thrown");
} catch (Exception e) {
 System.out.println("Exception caught!");
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look the Flow of a `try-catch-finally` Block

[image]